# question id is not updating according to the user_choice option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hope you all are well

I am creating a quiz application in which i have 3 models one question.rb, user.rb and result.rb

**Question.rb**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord

    validates :question, presence: true
    validates :option1, presence: true 
    validates :option2, presence: true 
    validates :option3, presence: true 
    validates :option4, presence: true 
    validates :answer, presence: true


end
```

**migrated file**

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.text :question
      t.text :option1
      t.text :option2
      t.text :option3
      t.text :option4
      t.text :answer

  
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**result.rb**

```
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.text :user_choice

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Also question_id and User_id are the Foreign keys in this table.

**result controller**

```
class ResultController < ApplicationController
  
       def create
            @result=Result.create(user_choice: params[:user_choice], 
            question_id: params[:question_id], 
            user_id: current_user.id)
    end
    
end
```

and finally
**view/question/index**

```
<div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
    <div class="card-body ">
       <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
      <div class="row py-5">
          <div class="p-5">
          <div class="text-center">
       <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4 ">Multiple-Choice Questions</h1>
        </div>

     
    <%= form_with model: @result ,url: result_path do |f| %>
   <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
        <p><%= question.question %></p>
        
        <% choices = [question.option1, question.option2, question.option3, question.option4] %>
        <% choices.each do |c| %>
            <div>
                <%= f.radio_button :"user_choice[#{question.id}]", c %>
                <%= f.label :user_choice, c  %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<% end %>
       <div class="sub"> <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %></div>
<% end %>
<div class="para1"><%= link_to 'New Question', new_question_path,class:"btn btn-primary btn-user" %>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Now everything is working perfectly the user choice is saving and user id is also saving current_user.id

Now the issue is question_id is not updating it's always show the id the last question have. In my cause it's 11. I don't know why it's not storing the id of the answered question.

Please i will be thankful if somebody help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.text :user_choice

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

There is no `question_id` attribute for a `result` record.

If you meant to connect `Question` to `Result` you need to define the relationships on the models:

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :results
end

class Result < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And you'll need your foreign keys on `Result`:

```rb
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.text :user_choice
      t.references :question
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now `Result` will have `question_id` and `user_id`